# automatically prevent performance regressions

Tags: performance, testing, tdd, performance-testing

Whenever I have a bug, my first piece of work is to write a failing test that shows that the bug exists. When added to my automated test suite, this test serves to ensure that the bug doesn't appear again.

With performance bugs, however, I'm unable to do this. Any assertion of performance would only be correct on my own machine, and not appropriate to check in to an automated test suite. This takes my usual tool for preventing regression out of my bag.

How do you prevent performance regressions in your own code?

An ideal answer:

- Is language agnostic.
- Prevents regressions from getting shipped, automatically.
- Provides the usual dev cycle: checkout, patch, regression-test, checkin.
- Works for open-source projects, where devs don't necessarily know the "usual" performance.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, tough problem.

As you have indicated in your question, the crux of the problem is the differences in environments i.e. between your development box and the test/QA environment.

To mitigate against performance regressions you could set-up a continuous deployment environment e.g. as well as automatically deploying to a test environment, you should also deploy to a QA environment which has operating parameters as similar to the final Production environment as possible (e.g. similar hardware, similar sized data set, etc.). This is commonly known as ["Build once, Deploy many"](http://earlyandoften.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/build-once-deploy-many/)

[image]

With this continuous deployment system in place you should also include acceptance tests to check for performance constraints e.g. the system should respond to a request within x milliseconds/seconds, a common non-functional requirement (NFR). When your code is then checked-in, it would be then tested automatically against these environments so you can quickly see when performance issues arise.

To help debug these performance issues you'd ideally also record performance metrics whilst running the tests. These test might then give you a good indicator as to where the problem may be manifesting itself e.g. you'll be able to see that a particular method is taking the majority of time to complete.

This set-up is difficult to establish in practice, but it would definitely allow you to "fail fast" and detect performance issues quickly.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this solution requires me to check in before testing. Also, is such a system applicable to small open-source projects?

Comment: I agree that a small performance unit test would be the only way to see the issue without a full build, but it's definitely not a broadly applicable solution. You mentioned you do this for a bug-fix. Are there other characteristics of these questionably performing methods you could test, such as a mock that counts expensive calls, and flags you if you don't meet O(n) performance, or another similar metric? Alternately, you could use a code profiler, but they're not normally automated.

Comment: It depends on what scale and environments you expect your OS project to be used in. As I said in my answer the key problem is the difference in environments. As I said in my answer, and as @JohnDeters says you could also run automatic metric testing or a code profiler to determine which methods are taking a disproportionate amount of time to complete, but this will still not tell you whether this will be an issue in your production environment or not.

Comment: @JohnDeters: Programmers are notoriously bad at guessing which calls are the expensive ones. We can easily automate the profiler, but what I can't figure out, what I guess I'm looking for prior art on, is the automated analysis of the profile. eg: `f()` took 3ms. Is this a failure?

Comment: The analysis may not be automatable.  What I do is run the app with the profiler capturing data from a normal execution.  I then sort the calls by % of time spent - what floats nearest the top are my bottlenecks.  I might find a tiny routine being called thousands of times, or a massive inefficient routine that's only called a few times. Optimizing one branch in the tiny routine can give an overall speedup, whereas the big routine might need more thought. But that's all in how you approach it.  It's still more of a craft than a formula.

Comment: You could start by using the profiler to identify which routines should have performance tests.  Maybe the profiler highlightes the called routines, but whatever routine calls them needs to be monitored for performance?  Then focus on testing the most impacted.  Maybe routines called more than 1000 times a second need complexity < 5.  Maybe you can mock in a counter that fails a test if it exceeds 10,000 iterations, or recurses to a depth > 8, or whatever fits your app?  Otherwise, you might punt it to the automated system tester.

Comment: What @JohnDeters does regarding the sorting of the calls by % of time spent is also what I do. However the bottlenecks which will be identified might have no adverse impact on the performance of the target system. Again, to know whether it will have an impact on the final system you need to test it in an environment which is as similar to the target system as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have used two different approaches to this sort of problem.

1. As @Fresh suggested monitoring performance on a realistic, possibly live, environment is a good option. That avoids both false positive and false negative results you might see on a development environment. That may have to occur post-commit but it is also the only tool I can think of to try to catch interactions between system components which might never show up as a performance issue locally or with different data sets.
2. Some metrics from a development environment which can be run pre-checkin still give useful hints about possible performance problems. In particular I like to have my test suite report on the slowest N tests in each unit/integration/acceptance category. While far from a sure indicator new appearances in those results or an increase in test run times are a good hint of a performance problem. This helps keep the test suites' runtime down as well which is also valuable.

Comment: Is there any system above that prevents performance regressions from getting shipped? On an open-source project, many of the devs will be running the test suite for the first time, so a simple listing won't help them. Monitoring the live environment means that any problems found are already shipped.

Comment: In the case of an open source library I would monitor an environment using the library as a proxy. That should at least allow you to make repeated measurements of one set of load tests in a sample environment every time you release (or prepare to release) a library version and help you catch catastrophic performance regressions.